# How to make requirements.txt-like file with bower?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

I've started working with `bower`, and it seems really helpful. I come from a python background, and so I'm used to having `virtualenv` and `requirements.txt`.

Since I'd rather not store all my dependencies in source control if I can help it, I was wondering, **how can I create a file like `requirements.txt` with `bower`?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After poking around a bit more, I have the solution.

`bower` uses a file called `bower.json` (formerly `component.json`) which is similar to a `Gemfile` or `requirements.txt`.

It *can* be created manually, and will look something like this...

```
{
    "name": "<app name, defaults co current folder name>",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "backbone": "~0.9.10",
        "underscore": "~1.4.3"
    }
}
```

However, **the piece that I was missing was to include the `--save` flag when installing packages in `bower`**:

```
bower install <package_name> --save
```

Unfortunately, I do not believe there is a way to set this behaviour by default using the  `.bowerrc` file.

As an added tidbit, once you have a `bower.json` file, installing your dependencies is as simple as running `bower install`.